# Quickbooks online essentials: how to see a "Currency" column in the Accounts list?

Tags: quickbooks

The help text says I should be seeing a Currency column in the Chart of Accounts, I am in the "Essentials" version, and I'm not seeing "Currency". Is it possible to have different currencies for different accounts?

[image]